# How to reset all sibling-components other than the clicked one in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a list of components `<Box />` and basically, it's a square div of `background-color: blue`, now what I want is when I click on a Box its background turns into red, while other Boxes reset to blue (to indicate that the red one is the selected one)

```
<Wrapper>
  <Box />
  <Box />
</Wrapper>
```

In vanilla JS I would've `document.querySelectAll` boxes and iterate through each box, but I'm new to react so how do I do this

Comment: You can simply attach click listner to each box appropriately. `<Box onClick={()=>{  //do Something }} >`

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the styling solution you're using, but generally speaking, you need to save the currently active box in a state (see React's `useState` hook if you're not familiar with it) and then style the active one to red background while otherwise it's blue.

To do this you should probably give some identifier to the boxes. Then when a box is clicked, you save that identifier to the state.

Answer (score 0):

In React you have to think a little bit differently than Vanilla JS when you are manipulating DOM.

Let's consider we have a unique `id` to every `<Box />` component. Then create a state to store selected boxes id. When you select a `Box` component update the state with its `id`. So now we know which box is selected. By comparing the state's id with `Box`s id we can easily update the background color. The following code snippet might help you.

```
const App = () => {
    const [ selectedBox, setSelectedBox ] = useState(null);

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <Box onClick={() => setSelectedBox('box1')} isActive={selectedBox === 'box1'} />
            <Box onClick={() => setSelectedBox('box2')} isActive={selectedBox === 'box2'} />
        </Wrapper>
    )
}

const Box = ({ onClick, isActive }) => {
    return(
        <div onClick={onClick} style={{ backgroundColor: isActive ? 'red' : 'blue'}}>
            Box
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, I was maintaining state inside the Box Component only so I added a state to the Wrapper. That was great to know